# How can I negate a unary operator in Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to perform the following in Apache but without having to resort to using the else directive:

```
<If "-e %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
</If>
<Else>
  # Do something
</Else>
```

I presume it is possible to negate the -e somehow but I'm not sure how.

Comment: [use `! -e ` probably](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html)

Comment: That's what I thought but this causes an Internal Server Error when I do so.

Comment: So the following works on Windows Apache 2.4 but not on the Debian Apache 2.4...

<If "!-e %{REQUEST_FILENAME}">
</If>